# How can I use GCrypt within an Objective-C (Cocoa) app for Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

Hey,
I need to use the GCrypt library from within an XCode Objective-C project. I'm totally new to programming with such so apologies if this is a somewhat silly question.
Is this possible and, if so, how may I go about it?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: How *totally new*? Have you written any code before? Have you used any C libraries before in C or Obj-C?

Comment: (I ask because this is a fairly advanced topic, and you should be at least comfortable with the basics of compiling and linking (without using XCode) before you can happily play with a C library) - Try working your way through the general libcrypt docs, and even write a small C program to *test drive* using it so you can feel more comfortable.

Comment: Yep, I've got experience in C and a lot more. I just haven't got much experience with GCrypt and Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C in Objective C directly, so you would access GCrypt as you would in regular C.

At the most basic level, include the libcrypt source in your project and then use

```
#include <gcrypt.h>
```

In source files that you need to access the gcrypt api.

For some general info on [using libraries in Xcode see this](http://www.soulstorm-creations.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=91%3ainstalling-portable-libraries-on-os-x&catid=18%3aprogramming-articles&Itemid=39) (Also includes a script called FrameworkMaker which can turn a generic library into a `.framework` file.)

Comment: I get errors, presumably because it isn't being linked. How can I do that in XCode?